# Is it possible to user quickblox on my own server?

Tags: android, video, quickblox, videochat

I want to create an android app that has a video calling feature in ti. Is it possible to make use of quickblox api/sdk with my own server?

Comment: quickblox  have its own server there is no need if u want somethink that time u need your server

Comment: yes, but is it possible to use quickblox with my own server or not?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to run Quickblox software on your own servers. As it states on their [enterprise page](http://quickblox.com/enterprise/): "QuickBlox is a friend of enterprise as it's scalable, secure, not a black box & can run on your servers with your / 3rd party IT team supporting it".

Their dedicated instances (AKA enterprise) plans actually require you to use your own servers, and from my experience, they simply setup the software on my AWS instances. A caveat though, is that it seems like Quickblox is built for AWS and relies on one or more AWS specific plugins. Porting it to another comparable platform may not be difficult, but you'll either have to undertake the engineering effort yourself or work something out with Quickblox in your enterprise contract.

If you don't have to money to throw at Quickblox to solve your video calling needs, then I would suggest hosting your own [Openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) server. OpenFire is a completely open-source XMPP server, and even has a plugin called Jingle Nodes, which can solve your video calling needs.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that's possible. And, I don't think they'll make an exception and allow you to use your own server. They would want you to buy their "Dedicated Instance" plan instead. Just check their [plans](http://quickblox.com/plans/) page for reference.